# Running timeit in a finite loop while timing subprocess calls leads to an infinite loop stuck on the first loop argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, functools

Given a function that loops over arguments and times a subprocess call, I'm wondering why instead of looping through the loop arguments, the runtime gets stuck in an infinite loop running the first argument?

Minimal example:

```
from subprocess import run
from timeit import timeit
from functools import partial
def echome(txt):
    run(['echo', txt])
for i in ['a','b','c']:
    echo_wrap = partial(echome, i)
    timeit(echo_wrap)
```

I'd expect the code to echo "a", "b", "c", then terminate.
However, it keeps printing "a" forever

Python env

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34)
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
```

**solved**
Misunderstood the function, it runs the function 1,000,000 times as detailed in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit)

Comment: You realize `timeit` is going to call your function `1_000_000` times by default, right?

Comment: By default `timeit` will run the passed statement/callable 10000 times and return the time taken. You can override the number of runs by passing the `number` argument

Comment: I see, misunderstood the function. Thanks!